# how to add a .xls to data base with datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, insert

I Have a methode that return a datatable value and i want insert it to a table in database what i should do?
**My Methode:**

```
public DataTable Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension)
{
    string conStr = "";
    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
    }
    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, "YES");
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

    //Get the name of First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    connExcel.Close();

    //Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

**My DataBase**

```
CREATE TYPE udt_MyTable AS TABLE
(
     [CID]          BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CEmail]       VARCHAR (250)  NOT NULL,
    [UID]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [CName]        NVARCHAR (450) NULL,
    [CorpName]     NVARCHAR (350) NULL,
    [Password]     BINARY (150)   NULL)
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_MyProcedure
(
    @TVP as dbo.udt_MyTable readonly -- NOTE: table valued parameteres must be readonly
)
AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBLCustomers]

 ([CEmail]
           ,[UID]
           ,[CName]
           ,[CorpName]
           ,[Password])
SELECT 
[CEmail]
           ,[UID]
           ,[CName]
           ,[CorpName]
           ,[Password]
FROM @TVP
```

**My Code:**

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                            ConnectionStrings["ZagmaDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                FileManagement FM = new FileManagement();
                string ext = ".xls";

                dt = FM.Import_To_Grid(Server.MapPath(FU.FileName), ext);
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("stp_MyProcedure", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TVP", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I want Know how to do for work with this method for insert to TBLCustomers

Comment: Does your datatable have a fixed structure (I mean, are there always the same columns)? Also, what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: 1.yes my table is fixed 2.sql-server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Sql server 2008 has introduced a feature called [Table valued parameters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.105).aspx)
The Idea is that you create a [user defined table type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx) and use it as a parameter to a stored procedure, allowing you to send tabled structure data to that stored procedure.
The .Net framework's ADO.Net fully supports this parameter type, and it's quite easy to work with.

So, here is a very simplified example on how to do it.

**First**, create a UDT that matches your data table structure. Since it's only a demo I'll show a simple table with only 2 columns:

```sql
CREATE TYPE udt_MyTable AS TABLE
(
    @Id int,
    @Text varchar(50)
)
```

**Then** you need to incorporate that type into a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_MyProcedure
(
    @TVP as dbo.udt_MyTable readonly -- NOTE: table valued parameteres must be readonly
)
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.ActualTable (Id, Text)
SELECT Id, Text
FROM @TVP

GO
```

**Now** all you have to do is execute the procedure from your c# code:

```cs
using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("stp_MyProcedure", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TVP", SqlDbType.Structured).value = dt;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**Note**: Table valued parameters are .net data tables passed to the stored procedure as `SqlDbType.Structured`.

Comment: i have error:An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no row at position 0. in  this line of methode: `string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();`

Comment: Ok, but how is that exception relevant to my answer?

Comment: i don't  understad your question

Comment: Well, that makes two of us. How is an exception on that line code relevant in any way to the answer I gave about sending a datatble to the datagbase?

Comment: My Code is Updated If need to show my database say it and Thanks :)

Comment: Look, my answer was about sending a c# data table into an sql server stored procedure. the exception you are talking about is about getting the values from the excel file. This is a totally different question now and I suggest you treat it like such - Ask a new question with the relevant code and the exception you get. There are a few benefits for you doing that - the main is that a lot more people will see the question so your chances of getting the correct answer sooner are much better.

Comment: yes your answer is true i should take better question now you can answer my problem?

Comment: The last time I've worked with excel was over a year ago. I don't remember enough of that to help this specific question.

Comment: no problem but thanks if  you can see my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251294/how-can-i-create-a-multi-value-for-a-column