# How can I create a multi value for a column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

I have two tables `TBLCustomers` and `TBLGroupCustomers`. I want to insert multi value in a third table that

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBLG_Groups] 
(
    [GrId]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CEmail] VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [GName]  NVARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
    [CName]  NVARCHAR (450) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GrId] ASC, [CEmail] ASC, [GName] ASC)
)
```

`CEmail`, `CName` from `TBLCustomers` and `GName` from `TBLGroupCustomers`

To do this, I created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.spG_Groups
    @CEmail VARCHAR(250),
    @GName NVARCHAR (70),
    @CName NVARCHAR(450)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TBLG_Groups(CEmail, GName, CName)
    VALUES (@CEmail, @GName, @CName)
END
```

Because I want show the name of customers join group I want each record of table have a single cname and gname,

C# code

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spG_Groups", conn);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

List<String> YrStrList1 = new List<string>(); 

foreach (ListItem li in chGp.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        YrStrList1.Add(li.Value);

        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CName", txtCName.Value));
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CEmail", txtemail.Value));
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GName", YrStrList1.ToString()));

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

It's not working what do I for this?

Comment: What do you mean by muti value field

Comment: Have you **debugged** your code? Does that stored procedure ever get executed? What error (if any) do you get?? The way you've set up your code, the first execution *should* work, but after that, you keep adding the parameter to the `cmd1` that are **already** there - so that will cause problems..... add the parameters **once**, before the `foreach`, and then in the loop only **set the parameter values** - don't keep adding the parameters over and over again !

Comment: @TheGameiswar i mean i want save tow value for a field like this a `CEmail` have tow `GName`

Comment: @marc_s in  ` cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();`  i see this error : Procedure or function spG_Groups has too many arguments specified.

Comment: you never reset the list of parameters for the cmd1. so you get more and more parameters for it, while adding parameters in the foreach loop.

Comment: @MaximFleitling what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

You need to **define** the parameters **once**, before the `foreach` loop, and then just set their values on each iteration - something like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spG_Groups", conn))
{
     cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     // define the parameters *ONCE*
     cmd1.Parameters.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 450);
     cmd1.Parameters.Add("@CEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250);
     cmd1.Parameters.Add("@GName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 70);

     List<String> YrStrList1 = new List<string>(); 

     foreach (ListItem li in chGp.Items)
     {
         if (li.Selected)
         {
              YrStrList1.Add(li.Value);

              // just set the *VALUES* of the parameters
              cmd1.Parameters["@CName"].Value = txtCName.Value;
              cmd1.Parameters["@CEmail"].Value = txtemail.Value;
              cmd1.Parameters["@GName"].Value = YrStrList1.ToString();

              cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: it's worked but the `GName`'s value is: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @sadeq: well - it's a `List<String>` - when you call `.ToString()` on that, you get back the type - that's just the way it works. What do you really want to get from your list of strings??

Comment: i want insert exactly the name of `GName` because in other page i should show the `CName` According to `GName`